# Browser mousedown (and held) then drag cursor object out of bounds, object border turns blue, how do I control this?

Tags: html, css

In a browser when mousedown (and held) in object then drag cursor out of bounds, the object border turns blue, how do I change said color to something other than blue?

Above question pretty much is the issue, or the default behavior I would to control.  I have tried setting border color for various events in css file, i.e. focus, hover, active, visited, etc.  None of these are the right event that seems to set the border color for the specific scenario as stated in the title.  I am hoping someone knows which event or such this is?  Oh, using CherryPy so an pure HTML or CSS style solution is preferred.  I don't want to add PHP or Java support to this project unless I can't help it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... After starting with an empty css file... I systematically enabled each style needed, validating each one in turn.  There was no overlapped or conflicting styles.  Good news in this case.  After a bit of experimentation, I found a solution to the issue.  Creative use of hover and focus events.  For example, if the object is a button, in the css file, a style for button:hover, button:active:hover, button:focus, button:active:focus, setting the attributes consistently across all of the above.  This masked the default browser behavior where focus settings a blue highlight color, and hover does not paint the button in blue as well.  This is the behavior desired for the given project.

**For example...**

```
button:hover {
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
button:active:hover {
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
button:visited {
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
button:active:visited {
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
button:focus {
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
button:active:focus {
        outline: none;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Note, you will still need to provide the operator/user visible feedback on what is happening, in my project, the opacity of the button changes for hover and focus events, rather than the default color changes as noted.